# I have an fatal error on my funcyions.php

Tags: functions, pluggable, function-exists

can someone please help me with this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function main() on null in /home/customer/www/real-amnesti.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1255
```

I haven't edited anything in the functions.php or any code for that matter.

Comment: That's `$wp->main( $query_vars );`, meaning your $wp global is null. That should be initialised in wp_settings.php.

Comment: If you haven't changed any code I'd try a fresh update of the core WordPress, or if this has broken after an automatic update try rolling back a few versions to a last-known-good version in case something in WP core has broken one of your plugins or the theme and that's causing this. Off the top of my head I can't see how this is happening though.

Comment: Or have you updated your PHP version? That seems more likely to break like this to me, if the new version is rejecting a plugin or theme file.

Comment: (www.real-amnesti.com/wp-admin) a host of different stuff is appearing.

Comment: It looks like the mu plugin wp-content/mu-plugins/config_db.php is causing the problem. What's in that file / what's it trying to do? wp-settings.php loads mu-plugins (line 289) before it sets up the $wp global (line 438), so it looks like it's trying to do something not allowed by a mu-plugin. I'd guess that's including wp-blog-header.php, which might work on the frontend since the multi-include-guard $wp_did_header would have been set, but not from the admin site.